# CPP calling Python, undefined references (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, c++, raspberry-pi

I am trying to call a python script from my cpp script using the below programs, however the cpp script will not compile saying that there is an undefined reference to `Py_Initialize` and `PyRun_SimpleString`.

**What do I need to do to fix the makefile?**

(Cpp 11, python 2.7)

Cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <Python.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        Py_Initialize();
        while(1)
        {
                PyRun_SimpleString("print 'a'");
                usleep(1000);
        }
        Py_Finalize();
        return 0;
}
```

My Makefile is:

```
all: myserver

myserver: myserver.o
        g++ myserver.o -o myserver

myserver.o: myserver.cpp
        g++ -c myserver.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config/

clean:
        rm -rf *o myserver
```

This seemed to work, not a good solution though:

```
all: myserver

myserver:
        g++ myserver.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config/ -o myserver

clean:
        rm -rf *o myserver
```

Comment: Try moving the linker flags from the myserver.o target to the myserver target.

Comment: could you be specific in what I should have?

Comment: Try moving the "-lpython2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config" from the 7th line to the 4th. Can't currently test it myself since I'm on the go without access to my computer.

Comment: g++ myserver.o -o myserver -lpython2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config/ fails, undefined reference, as does putting the -o myserver at the end with the same config

Comment: Can you provide the complete error output and commands generated by the makefile?